# error 500 when using CSOM to authenticate

Tags: 2013

I'm using CSOM from an ASP .NET page in C# to authenticate against sharepoint online site, the code is working but sometimes I got a 500 error, I have discovered that sometimes this error comes with installing new features or web parts, after reseting the IIS server it becomes available again, but there is some times when I don't know why it occurs.

do you have any way of monitor this type of error to prevent it?
do you have any tip about solving the error? appart from reseting the server.

Comment: is this happening with SharePoint Online ? did you find your answer?